# Jetpack Compose UI Skipping Frames when observing StateFlow

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

My UI is skipping frames and the loading indicator isn't really spinning while the data is being fetched. I'm clearly making a mistake here when using flow, but I can't really understand where. Why is data not being loaded in the IO thread?

View Model with UI State class:

```
class DateSelectorViewModel(
    private val dateRepository: DataRepository = DataRepository()
) : ViewModel() {

    val stateUi: StateFlow<DateListUiState> = dateRepository.datesFlow.map { DateListUiState.Ui(it) }
        .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, DateListUiState.Loading)

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            dateRepository.loadDatesFromNetwork()
        }
    }

}

sealed class DateListUiState {
    object Loading : DateListUiState()
    data class Ui(val dates: List<String>) : DateListUiState()
}
```

Repository class:

```
class DataRepository(
    private val remoteDataSource: DateRemoteDataSource = DateRemoteDataSource()
) {

    val datesFlow: MutableSharedFlow<List<String>> = MutableSharedFlow()

    suspend fun loadDatesFromNetwork() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val dates = remoteDataSource.getDeliveryDate()
            datesFlow.emit(dates)
        }
    }

}
```

The Remote Data Source is simply a Retrofit implementation with a suspend call to fetch the dates and return them as list of strings.

Activity Class:

```
class DateSelectorActivity : ComponentActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val vm: DateSelectorViewModel = getViewModel { DateSelectorViewModel() }
        setContent {
            Theme {
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
                    val uiState by vm.stateUi.collectAsState()
                    DateListScreen(uiState = uiState, onDateClick = { clickedDate -> })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DateListScreen(uiState: DateListUiState, onDateClick: (String) -> Unit) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        when (uiState) {
            is DateListUiState.Loading -> CircularProgressIndicator()
            is DateListUiState.Ui -> LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(top = 8.dp)
            ) {
                items(uiState.dates, key = { it }) {
                    DateListItem(date = it, onDateClick = onDateClick)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I noticed is that if I use `SharingStarted.Lazily` instead of `SharingStarted.Eagerly` in the `stateIn()` method, the UI doesn't skip frames, but the UI never really updates after the network call is returned

What am I missing here? I must have really misunderstood a core concept here, because this is makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I failed to find what is specifically causing your problem, but you are doing the following improperly, and maybe in the course of correcting it, your problem will also go away.

The way you have your repo class set up is weird. You're making an external class separately have to call a specific suspend function to make your flow start working. Flows should be able to work automatically when collected. Additionally, it starts that flow by calling a suspend function, so it unusually acts like a synchronous function that doesn't return anything but makes you wait for it anyway. This would be a proper implementation of your repo class:

```
class DataRepository(
    private val remoteDataSource: DateRemoteDataSource = DateRemoteDataSource()
) {
    private val scope = SupervisorScope(Dispatchers.IO) + CoroutineName("DataRepository")

    val datesFlow: SharedFlow<List<String>> = flow {
        val dates = remoteDataSource.getDeliveryDate()
        emit(dates)
    }.shareIn(scope, SharingStarted.Lazily, replay = 1)
}
```

Then you can remove the `init` block from your view model class.

I am assuming that this is just a skeleton at this point, and you plan to create a data source that actually streams changing values instead of just fetching a single value. Fetching a single value is not what Flows are for.

---

Edit: based on your comment about plans to expand this to allow pushing from different sources to that same flow, your repo should look like:

```
class DataRepository(
    private val remoteDataSource: DateRemoteDataSource = DateRemoteDataSource()
) {
    private val scope = SupervisorScope(Dispatchers.IO) + CoroutineName("DataRepository")

    val datesFlow: MutableSharedFlow<List<String>> = MutableSharedFlow(replay = 1)

    fun loadDatesFromNetwork() {
        scope.launch {
            val dates = remoteDataSource.getDeliveryDate()
            datesFlow.emit(dates)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! This did indeed fix the issue! But It's still not very clear to me why it was happening to begin with.

Also this kinda breaks my original idea, I wanted the flow in the repo to act like a "stream" in which I could, from other functions inside the repo, "emit" new values to it.
My repo will fetch stuff from DB as well, and have some syncing mechanism between the network and the DB, and that's why I wanted the repo functions to be able to "emit" things into that flow, as I did in my original code. Depending on the function called externally, new values will be fetched from network/db

Comment: Try your original code but change the flow declaration to also have a replay: `val datesFlow: MutableSharedFlow<List<String>> = MutableSharedFlow(replay = 1)` Your original way of doing it **does** make sense if you are planning to expand it to allow different sources to push to that same flow. But since you don't know exactly when these values will arrive in relation to when downstream collectors will be reading them, you may need some replay greater than 0.

Comment: But to make sense semantically, I would change your suspend function into an async one as shown in my edit so in the ViewModel you just fire off the request without having to launch a coroutine to suspend and wait for nothing.